# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Files crashes when opening large folder

Tags: nautilus, crash

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Files crashes when opening large folder.

```
* 156,657 files
* 726.2GB total size
```

Other folders open fine
*They are mainly mp3 flac and a few jpg files
I got a crash window and send to ubuntu which I wasn't able to copy but mentioned core dump
This is what goes in sys log when it happens

```
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700004] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x100000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700013] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700020] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700031] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:a0:80:e0:04/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 4096 in
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700031]          res 41/40:00:80:e0:04/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700037] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.700041] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701521] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701542] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#20 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701546] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#20 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701549] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#20 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701554] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#20 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 e0 80 00 00 00 08 00 00
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701556] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 319616
Jul 24 21:45:19 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [ 8181.701592] ata1: EH complete
Jul 24 21:45:23 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M dbus-daemon[1865]: [session uid=1000 pid=1865] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=2031 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul 24 21:45:23 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M dbus-daemon[1865]: [session uid=1000 pid=1865] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Jul 24 21:45:42 john-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M gvfsd-metadata[2388]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
```

Thank you for the help so far......
I have found DISKS in Ubuntu and it states this
Disk is OK, 1664 bad sectors (43° C/109° F)
Could it be the VA folder has bad sectors?
All other folders open fine - The VA folder tries then crashes

Comment: How much memory is available on the system? What kinds of files are they? If they are image files it's likely the file browser is attempting to thumbnail them. In either case, it's possible that on a system without enough memory or swap space that it's running Out of Memory (OOM) and the process is then killed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please include some information on the nature of the crash to help others diagnose this problem. The relevant lines from /var/log/syslog or dmesg may help. Edit your question and add these info.

Comment: This error message implies hard disk is failing: `print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 319616`